# Ciclo while en javaweb me repite datos de mysql

Tags: java, html, jsp

Buenas noches tengo un problema que no entiendo el porque pasa y no se como evitarlo 
Estoy usando patrón MVC EN JSP usando librería de jstl.
Mi problema es que en la tabla de html se me repiten los datos de la ultima persona de la db de MySql si tengo 4 usuarios me imprime el ultimo usuario de la tabla 4 veces, osea me muestra el ultimo usuario de la tabla usuarios dependiendo la cantidad de registros en esa tabla

---

Clase USUARIODAO.

```
public List listar() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM empleado";
    List<CEmpleado> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        conn = cnobj.Conexion();
        ps = cnobj.PrepareSt(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            em.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            em.setDni(rs.getString(2));
            em.setNom(rs.getString(3));
            em.setTel(rs.getString(4));
            em.setEstado(rs.getString(5));
            em.setUser(rs.getString(6));
            lista.add(em);

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

---> Controlador

```
} else if (menu.equals("Empleado")) {
        switch (accion) {
            case "Listar":
                List lista = edao.listar();
                request.setAttribute("empleados", lista);
                break;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError();
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Empleado.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

---> html

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>DNI</th>
                        <th>NOMBRES</th>
                        <th>TELEFONO</th>
                        <th>ESTADO</th>
                        <th>USUARIO</th>
                        <th>ACCIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <c:forEach var="em" items="${empleados}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${em.getId()}</td> 
                        <td>${em.getDni()}</td>
                        <td>${em.getNom()}</td>
                        <td>${em.getTel()}</td>  
                        <td>${em.getEstado()}</td> 
                        <td>${em.getUser()}</td>  
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-warning" >Editar</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" >Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar dónde creas tu objeto `em`?

Comment: En usuariodao tengo la instancia fuera de los metodos
Tenerlo por fuera genera conflicto ?? deberia estar dentro del metodo list o dentro del metodo dentro del while por alguna razon ??
`CEmpleado em = new CEmpleado();`

Comment: Gracias a la pregunta donde esta el objeto encontré el error no sabia que la instancia debía estar dentro del ciclo while.
Gracias buen dia.

Comment: No obligatoriamente tiene que estar dentro del ciclo `while`, de hecho, no tendría sentido crearla dentro del ciclo, pues se crearía una instancia a cada iteracción del ciclo. Hice la pregunta porque puede que `em` estuviera recibiendo datos en otra parte.

Comment: Si recibe datos ejemplo de los métodos de filtrar validar al usuario en el login y demás, si lo dejara fuera del método debería tener otro nombre el objeto `em` ?? o como debería usarse el objeto para no tener dentro del ciclo ?? ya que me parece raro tener una instancia dentro de un método o ciclo

Comment: Eso depende de tu contexto. Si se trata de guardar **únicamente** los datos que obtienes en la consulta `SELECT * FROM empleado` tienes que crear la instancia dentro del método (no dentro del `while` que es otra cosa muy diferente). Si se trata de recoger más datos desde otros métodos de la clase, entonces tendrías que declararlo como miembro de la clase o irlo pasando en parámetro entre los diferentes métodos. Quizá te estaba repitiendo datos porque en otras partes de la clase ya ponías datos dentro de `em` ¿?

Comment: a ok listo , muchas gracias por los comentarios muy gran ayuda